# How to track URLs included in HTTPGet()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are using AMPscript HTTPGet to pull in some HTML dynamically. The issue is that the URLs are not being wrapped in ET's tracking so clicks aren't being logged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few parts to this answer.

First, you have to call your ExactTarget support rep and have them enable **WRAP HTTPGET URLS** for your account.

Second, all URLs in the HTTPGet that you want tracked must be preceeded by `httpgetwrap|`. So for instance, a full HTML url would look like. `<a href="httpgetwrap|http://www.example.com/">`. If you do not have the httpgetwrap| in the href, its also possible to use something like this:  `Replace(@content,'href="http','href="httpgetwrap|http')`.

Third, when you output the the HTML content, you must wrap it in `TreatAsContent()`.

The full code snippet should look something like this:

```
%%[
    var @getStatus, @getURL, @content
    set @getURL = "http://www.example.com"
    set @content = HttpGET(@getURL, false, 2, @getStatus)
    set @content = Replace(@content,'href="http','href="httpgetwrap|http')
]%%

%%=TreatAsContent(@content)=%%%
```

Update: If you are using a user-initiated send, you must have the "track all links" option selected or they will not be wrapped.

Comment: This is the way we generally do it.  I would point out that you're taking out the original `http` in your replace() line...and there's a couple of extra double-quotes.  It should be: `set @content = Replace(@content,'href="http','href="httpgetwrap|http')`

Comment: Updated, thanks. I actually didn't use the replace in my production code but added it for anyone who might find it useful. Probably should have actually tested it ;)